# Storybook webpack build freezes at 70% when I save a file in watch mode

Tags: webpack, watch, storybook

**Describe the bug**

When I run `npm run storybook` it runs ok, but when I save a file, it stucks and I have to kill the process and re-run again

**console output**

```
webpack building...
70% building 2277/2591 modules 314 active ...e-loader/dist/index.js??ref--11!/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/src/customer_portal/pages/HomePage/Categories/CardCategory.tsx✖ ｢wdm｣: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/index.js):
TypeError: string.toLowerCase is not a function
    at sanitize (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/csf/dist/index.js:27:17)
    at handleADD (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/abstract-syntax-tree/parse-helpers.js:173:15)
    at Controller.enter (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/abstract-syntax-tree/traverse-helpers.js:138:54)
    at Controller.__execute (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js:330:31)
    at Controller.traverse (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js:434:28)
    at Object.traverse (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/estraverse/estraverse.js:646:27)
    at findAddsMap (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/abstract-syntax-tree/traverse-helpers.js:132:14)
    at generateAddsMap (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/abstract-syntax-tree/generate-helpers.js:203:43)
    at generateStoriesLocationsMap (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/abstract-syntax-tree/generate-helpers.js:207:22)
    at inject (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/abstract-syntax-tree/inject-decorator.js:65:66)
    at readAsObject (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/dependencies-lookup/readAsObject.js:26:48)
    at readStory (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/dependencies-lookup/readAsObject.js:42:10)
    at Object._callee$ (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/build.js:47:48)
    at tryCatch (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)
    at Generator.next (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20)
    at /var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object._callee$ (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/build.js:102:13)
    at tryCatch (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)
    at Generator.next (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/build.js:26:103)
    at _next (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/build.js:28:194)
    at /var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/build.js:28:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/build.js:28:97)
    at Object.transform (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/build.js:31:21)
    at LOADER_EXECUTION (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:119:14)
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/sd/Service-Desk-Main/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:120:4)
70% building 2591/2591 modules 0 active
```

**Additional context**

The problem is not only in my computer. All developers experiment the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your story's title is a simple string or an object.
I have fixed this by converting the title to a string.